# Trying to fill a textbox depending on the selected value on my dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im new to ASP.Net MVC. and Ive been searching for about 2 hours and cant seem to get it.
I have a dropdownlist of products from the database. What i want is to fill the **textbox Description** on realtime depending on the selected item on my dropdownlist.

Here is what i have so far:

**Populate my dropdown list**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Products.Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = i.ProductName,
            Text = i.ProductName
        }
      );
        ViewBag.ProductItems = items;
        return View(); 
}
```

**My dropdown list**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetDescriptionByProductName", "PurchaseOrder", new AjaxOptions{ InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId = "description"}))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("ProductItems", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" }) 
        }
```

**Here is my ActionResult in my Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDescriptionByProductName(string ProductItems)
{
    var data = db.Products.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(ProductItems));
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[This is what it looks like. I select an item from the dropdownlist and it will autofill in the textbox description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozk9P.png)

UPDATE: All THIS DOES RIGHT NOW IS DIRECT ME BACK TO INDEX PAGE AND RESETS IT TO THE DEFAULT VALUE WHICH IS BLANK

Comment: If you're not using any framework that supports data binding, you'll have to manually update your textbox with javascript.

Comment: what im trying to do now is get the value of the selected item and throw it to the controller where it will search for a product name match and retrieve the description for that product.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this using ajax (to stay on the same page)?

Comment: yes thats what i was trying to do

Comment: Then you need to use `Ajax.BeginForm()` or better use `$.ajax()` to post the selected value. And you should be returning only the description property of the selected `Product` (not a collection of `Products`) and then you update the DOM in the success callback

Comment: @NelGarcia If all you want is to get the currently selected item from your dropdownlist, then it should already be available in your parameter *ProductItems*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code given snippet, I dont think its necessary to hit the server everytime to get the product description. I have created a fiddle here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1lyHWW

This is what I have done:

Created a  model for Product - You can reuse your Product model

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }         
        public string Display { get; set; }         
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

and in Action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var productsList = new List<Product>
    {
    new Product{Id= 1,Display = "Product 1", Description = "prod 1 description"},
    new Product{Id= 2,Display = "Product 2", Description = "prod 2 description"},
    new Product{Id= 3,Display = "Product 3", Description = "prod 3 description"},
    new Product{Id= 4,Display = "Product 4", Description = "prod 4 description"},
    new Product{Id= 5,Display = "Product 5", Description = "prod 5 description"},
            };

  ViewBag.Products = productsList;
  return View();
}
```

.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <select name="drpProducts" id="drpProducts">
                @{
                    foreach(var product in ViewBag.Products)
                    {
                        <option value="@product.Id"
                            data-desc="@product.Description">
                            @product.Display
                        </option>
                    }
                }
                </select>

            <input type="text" id="txtProductDescription"/>
            }



 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#drpProducts").change(function(){

                var selectedItemDesc = $("#drpProducts option:selected").attr("data-desc");
                $("#txtProductDescription").val(selectedItemDesc);

                });

        });
    </script>
```

*Note - I have used jQuery in this approach*

Comment: @NelGarcia - Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below steps
1. change event for changing the dropdown option
2. in the change event make ajax cal to controller-> action
3. show the received data in the textbox

Comment: `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetDescriptionByProductName", "PurchaseOrder", new AjaxOptions{ InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId = "description"}))
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("ProductItems", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" }) 
            }`

Comment: ^ it only redirects me back to my index page and refreshes and resets

Answer (score 0):

Inside the razor view (.cshtml file), you can have something like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetDescriptionByProductName", "PurchaseOrder"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Textbox")
        @Html.TextBox("txt", (string)ViewBag.selected)
        @Html.DropDownList("ProductItems", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Values,
             new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

And then inside your controller, something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetDescriptionByProductName(string ProductItems)
{
    var query = from d in db.Products
                where d.ProductName == ProductItems
                select d;

    // Here you can query your list of items for the passed in ProductItems
    ViewBag.selected = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductItems)?"NONE": ProductItems;

    return Json(query);
}
```

Or you may also use ajax as others have suggested using `$.ajax` to call the same action method and passing your selectedItemId which you can get using jQuery like: `$('select[name="ProductItems"]').val()`.

Hope this helps.